# Header image with CSS in Bootstrap theme always changes back to default

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Bootstrap 3 (part of the problem), and I'm trying to set up a quick portfolio site for a class. I'm using the One Page Wonder starter template from here: http://startbootstrap.com/one-page-wonder. I've got a problem with the one-page-wonder.css stylesheet. I'm trying to change the header image from the placeholder, and I added a style for an essay, but neither change shows up when I drop it onto the server. I have deleted the entire bootstrap folder on my server and reuploaded it, but whenever I go to my page and check the code, it shows the same placeholder image and the same old style sheet. Here's the style I want to use:

```
.essay {
    text-indent:50px;
}

.header-image {
    background:url(/images/Fire.jpg) no-repeat center center cover;
    background-position:top;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here's a link to the page: http://jonathanalumbaugh.altervista.org/courserequests/photographyone.html

It's really annoying, I've looked through all the code, but it always reverts to this placehold.it thing. I've tried clearing out cookies, cached images, and files, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying your CSS style incorrectly. You are passing an invalid value to `background-image` - that property expects only the URL to the image.

You are looking to set the `background` property, which is a shorthand property for multiple other properties. You can use it like this:

```
 background: #000 url(/images/Fire.jpg) center center no-repeat;
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

You should always ensure your CSS is valid:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Note: Your image *still* can't be found. Where is it?

You can't include `cover` in the background shorthand, you need to do something like this:

```
html { 
  background: url(/get/the/right/url.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It was originally correct, just "background" and not "background-image," I changed it to see if that'd fix anything. I just changed it back, and weirdly enough, now the .essay class works, but my image still isn't showing up.

Comment: Well, this 404 might have something to do with it: http://jonathanalumbaugh.altervista.org/images/Fire.jpg Check your path.

Comment: Wow. I guess I'm using absolute paths rather than relative. Sorry for the stupid question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I kinda jumped the gun, the image still isn't coming up. I figured out why things weren't updating, CloudFlare was caching stuff, so I turned that off. But if you take a look at the site, the image isn't showing. The URL is now absolute, but nothing. Any ideas? Sorry about that.

Comment: Your site is still using `background-image`, not `background`. And the link to the image is still throwing a 404. Please check your path and also *check your CSS with this validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/*

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me here. I did change `background-image` to `background`, and the path is correct (http://www.jonathanalumbaugh.altervista.com/courserequests/images/Fire.jpg), and the change is showing for me so I wonder what's up with that. I did run the validator, and here's what it gives me: **Value Error : background cover is not a background-color value : url(http:/www.jonathanalumbaugh.altervista.com/courserequests/images/Fire.jpg) no-repeat center center cover**

Comment: Updated again. Dude, fix the 404 or we'll get nowhere.

Comment: What's giving you a 404? The `background` url is set to jonathanalumbaugh.altervista.com/courserequests/images/Fire.jpg which seems to be working (I'm not sure I can be sure anymore, haha). Sorry I don't have enough rep to move this to a chat, I generally figure stuff out myself, but this thing is stumping me.

Comment: The URL in the stylesheet is: http:/www.jonathanalumbaugh.altervista.com/courserequests/images/Fire.jpg... Note the single slash after the semi-colon Change to `http://`

Comment: Oh my gosh. I can't believe I made that mistake. So I fixed that but I've still got nothing. **facepalm** Got it! I had to have the correct link in `background-image`. I feel pretty stupid now.

Comment: No... You have your `background` declaration wrong. You can't specify `cover` in the `background` shorthand property. Please refer to my update in my answer. And ensure your CSS is valid!

Comment: Got it. I updated everything, validated my CSS, and it's all working great. Thanks so much for all your help!